# How can I create a simple text file that contains more than one line of text with CHEF?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am trying to create a CHEF recipe that creates a text file with more than one line of text for testing purposes. I have tried using content but that just wrote out to one line. I have searched for a few hours now and still have not found a good way to do this. Is there a better way to do it instead of using content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use either the `file` resource or `template` resource, depending on if you wanted simple inline content, or a more complex Erb template:

```
file '/foo' do
  content "line one\nline two\n"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I was approaching the situation from the wrong angle. This does work however so I will mark it as the accepted answer.